# C# Linq add elements from one list<custom> to another comparing them and changing values

Tags: c#, list, linq, compare, ienumerable

I was trying to implement functionality that allows 2 lists to be compared, and if there is a identical value (id) in both, second list will overlay that element values in first list, else element from second list will be added

```
private List<PotionManager.Potion.Eff> effs = new List<PotionManager.Potion.Eff>();

public string id
{
    set
    {
        var _effs = new List<PotionManager.Potion.Eff>(PM.GetEffectsOnPotion(value).Select(x => x.Clone()));
        foreach (PotionManager.Potion.Eff _eff in _effs)
        {
            var eff = effs.Find(x => x.id == _eff.id);
            if (eff != null)
            {
                eff.power = _eff.power;
                eff.time = _eff.time;
            }
            else
            {
                effs.Add(_eff);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is there a more efficient way doing that instead of foreach?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: You can create a ISet(for example HashSet) by PotionManager.Potion.Eff.id to improve performance using `SomeSet.Contains(_eff.id)` instead of `effs.Find(x => x.id == _eff.id)`

Comment: You can try using the IEqualityComparer interface and just use methods "Except" or "Intersect" to do all your comparisons and remove the foreach

  please refer the MSDN doc on the same : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserComparer : IEqualityComparer<User>
{
    public bool Equals(User x, User y) => x.Id == y.Id;
    public int GetHashCode(User obj) => base.GetHashCode();
}
```

in main method:

```
var list1 = new List<User>
    {
        new User{Id = 1, Name = "Ted" },
        new User{Id = 2, Name = "Jhon" },
        new User{Id = 3, Name = "Alex" }
    };
var list2 = new List<User>
    {
        new User{Id = 2, Name = "Jhon" },
        new User{Id = 3, Name = "Alex" },
        new User{Id = 4, Name = "Sam" },
    };

var result = list1.Union(list2, new UserComparer());
```

the result will contains 4 elements: 
 1 Ted, 2 Jhon, 3 Alex, 4 Sam

I hope this helps you